# HTML table cell contents are wrapping when using Bootstrap CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Within a HTML table cell, I have a text input element, followed by some standard text. I want both items to be inline.

This works fine until I import bootstrap.css, at which point the items are shown on separate lines, as if a line break exists between them.

I am unsure on how to "override" whatever styling bootstrap is applying.

Please see my JS Fiddle below. I have included the bootstrap.min.css resource.

You can see that the text input field and string "m" are on separate lines within each cell.

Once you remove the Bootstrap.css external resource, and press run again, the items are inline.

How can I override whatever styling the Bootstrap CSS is applying? (I need Bootstrap CSS for other things).

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/87tdupys/9/

```
<!--Desired: text input field plus text "m" inline. However, Bootstrap.min.css is causing the 2 items to display on separate lines. This can be shown by removing the external reference to bootstrap.min.css (in the left hand External Resources pane). How can I override this behaviour, and force the 2 items to be inline?-->

<table id='assetConfigLayoutTable' border='1px'>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <label>Capacity A</label>
    </td>
    <td style="width:200px">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px;"> m
    </td>

    <td>
      <label>Capacity B</label>
    </td>
    <td style="width:200px">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:50px"> m
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `twitter-bootstrap` by default `.form-control` is block level element, you need to make it `inline-block` element.

```
.form-control{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxsw2n8s/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

Or put a div with class `form-inline` in the `td`

https://jsfiddle.net/87tdupys/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
just take a new class name beside the form-control and put the below code in 
your css
<style>
 .text-display
  {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
</style>
<table id='assetConfigLayoutTable' border='1px'>

<tr>
  <td>
    <label>Capacity A</label>
  </td>
  <td style="width:200px">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-display" 
   style="width:50px;"> m
  </td>

  <td>
    <label>Capacity B</label>
  </td>
  <td style="width:200px">
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-display" style="width:50px"> 
    m
  </td>
 </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just place a important `!important` in your custom css ,

Hope it works for you

and there was no fiddle link.....